# Pass and get variables between PHP and R

Tags: php, r

I have a php file that runs as a cron job. That file gets all the football games of the day with curl once per day and stores them in a database. So the table `nextgames` has the following:

> HomeTeam, AwayTeam, League, Odds of various things such as 1,X,2 under etc (doesn't matter).

For each of those games I want to run some R code. So basically, inside the php script I need to run a command like:

```
exec("Rscript <path>/myscript.R");
```

My first question is: In that script I need to pass HomeTeam, AwayTeam and League. So how do I pass those variables to the script?

My second question is: That script has as a result a 7x7 matrix that represents the probabilities for each of the teams score 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 goals. How do I get that data back to php?

PS: I can't install rapache to the webhost I am atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the example on the `proc_open` docs page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

What I would suggest is outputting the contents of your matrix as some portable format, such as JSON (it appears R can do JSON).  Then just json_decode the output from the R script.

Comment: first time i am seeing proc_open (a bit new to php) a lot of things to read. Will read it and give it a try. Will come back with the results.

Comment: If you are just `exec`ing the R script, and only need to read the output and not provide any input, then you could use `popen` instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php in "r" (read) mode.

Comment: I need to pass input as well (The 2 teams and the league to create the poisson regression) so i guess the proc_open is what i am looking for. But from docs i am reading it says that "If you are, like me, tired of the buggy way proc_open handles streams and exit codes; this example demonstrate the power of pcntl, posix and some simple output redirection:" what does buggy way means?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  I have used proc_open many times, in production code, without problem.

Comment: Hehe.I will give it a try. I am pretty sure one of the solutions (either with proc_open or json or the other one the guy suggests) will work without any problems. If not i guess i will come back with another question. Thanks for the help.